# D3 scatterplot newbe

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to D3 and need a simple scatterplot.

The problem is that the data is not showing up where I want it to show up. I made some test data giving values for x and y between 100 an 200 but the dots
always seem to be in the same place on the screen. What I change to domain or range they show up on the same place. I think It must be something fundamental but I cant find it. **Please give me a clue.**

This is the code from the test:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
            
    <!-- Load d3.js -->
    <script src="d3.v6.js"></script>
            
    <!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
    <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
    
    <script>
    
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
            width = 920 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);
    
    
            let dataExample = [];
    
            for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 100;
                const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 100;
                dataExample.push([x, y]);
            }
    
    //Read the data (DataFile.csv is NOT used. Using data from dataExample
    d3.csv("DataFile.csv").then( function(data) {
    
        // Add X axis
        const x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10000])
        .range([ 0, width ]);
        svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    
        // Add Y axis
        const y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10000])
        .range([ height, 0]);
        svg.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    
        // Add dots
        svg.append('g')
        .selectAll("dot")
        .data(dataExample)
        .join("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { return d[0]; } )
            .attr("cy", function (d) { return d[1]; } )
            //console.log(dataExample)
            .attr("r", 1.5)
            .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
    
    })
    </script>
```

[image]

The axes are 0 to 10000 but the plotted data shows op between y=7200 to 8800 and x=800 and 2500.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your `x` and `y` scales when setting the "cx" and "cy" attributes of the circles. Right now you're setting these attributes to the values in your data, without using the scales. This code should look like this:

```js
svg.append('g')
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataExample)
  .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d[0]); } )
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d[1]); } )
    .attr("r", 1.5)
    .style("fill", "#69b3a2");
```

The purpose of the `x` and `y` scales in the scatterplot are to map values in your data to positions in the scatterplot.

With this fix, you'll likely want to update the domains of the scales to better match the values in the data, such as by using [d3.extent](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#extent) to get the min and max values.